# regsub/regex parsing on list of elements in tcl

Tags: tcl

I need to convert a string with list with more than one elements (`<>,abcd1,1,1`) as like below.

From:

```
test={abc([(<>,yifow3,1,1),(abc,yifow3,2,2,20140920,20151021),(<>,yifow3,3,3,20140920,20151021),(<>,yifow3,4,4)])}
```

To:

```
abc([(yifow3,1,1),(yifow3,2,2),(yifow3,3,3),(yifow3,4,4)])
```

I tried to extract the list inside `abc([])` using the below `regsub`. always it will have "abc([" at the begining and "])" at the end.

```
regsub -all {(abc\(\[)([a-z0-9\<\>\(\),]+)(\)\])} $test {\2} test2
```

then from `test2`, using the for loop to extract the second, third, fourth items from each elements (`<>,abcd1,1,1`).

Is there any simple way to extract using regsub/regex instead of for loop?

regex should extract second, third and fourth items ignoring first and fifth and sixth if they presents.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do or the logic of how to get from the input to the string you want to get. Can you please elaborate on your question? For example, is there always `abc([` at the beginning? Are the things you want to keep always `yifow3` and numbers after it? Why is the third paren `(yifow3,3)` and not `(yifow3,3,3)`, etc?

Comment: Sorry, it should (yifow3,3,3). always it will have "abc([" at the begining and "])" at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regsub -all -expanded {
    \(                        # a literal parenthesis
    [^(,]+ ,                  # 1 or more non-(parenthesis or comma)s and comma
    ( [^,]+ , \d+ , \d+ )     # the 3 fields to keep with commas
    [^)]*                     # 0 or more non-parenthesis chars
    \)                        # a literal parenthesis
} $test {(\1)}
```

returns

```
abc([(yifow3,1,1),(yifow3,2,2),(yifow3,3,3),(yifow3,4,4)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based strictly on what you have in your question, you could first get all the things inside the innermost paren with a regex if you are already sure the string begins with `abc([` and ends with `])`:

```
set test {abc([(<>,yifow3,1,1),(abc,yifow3,2,2,20140920,20151021),(<>,yifow3,3,3,20140920,20151021),(<>,yifow3,4,4)])}
set items [regexp -all -inline -- {\([^()]+\)} $test]
# (<>,yifow3,1,1) (abc,yifow3,2,2,20140920,20151021) (<>,yifow3,3,3,20140920,20151021) (<>,yifow3,4,4)
```

Then you can loop through each (split on comma, get the 2nd to 4th elements and join them back, etc).

I don't think you can avoid using a loop if you want to keep it simple. You can skip a few steps I guess with a more elaborate (no more simple!) regex:

```
set test {abc([(<>,yifow3,1,1),(abc,yifow3,2,2,20140920,20151021),(<>,yifow3,3,3,20140920,20151021),(<>,yifow3,4,4)])}
set items [regexp -all -inline -- {\([^,()]+((?:,[^,()]+){3})} $test]
set results [lmap {a b} $items {list [string trim $b ,]}]
# yifow3,1,1 yifow3,2,2 yifow3,3,3 yifow3,4,4
```

---

The regex here `\([^,()]+((?:,[^,()]+){3})` matches as follows:

```
\(                 # Literal opening paren
[^,()]+            # Any character except ',', '(' and ')'
(
  (?:,[^,()]+){3}  # A comma followed by any character except ',', '(' and ')',
                   # the whole thing 3 times
)
```

---

I used [`lmap`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm) (Tcl8.6) here which is basically a kind of loop. You can change it a bit to get the string you are looking for:

```
set results [lmap {a b} $items {list "([string trim $b ,])"}]
set output "abc(\[[join $results ,]])"
# abc([(yifow3,1,1),(yifow3,2,2),(yifow3,3,3),(yifow3,4,4)])
```